# Count distinct All value until current row

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I just want to get New customers reference from previous month
So the formula I decide is count distinct 'Buyer_Username' value from first row until current row subtract with count distinct 'Buyer_Username' from first row to previus month ref from current row
With first query to extract month and Year from main_table,

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y', Created_Time) AS Year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Created_Time) AS Month_Number,
  FORMAT_DATE('%B', Created_Time) AS Month,
  Buyer_Username,
FROM Main_table
```

Which on main_table I have only 1 date column name 'Created_time' in Datetime format

| Year | Month_Number | Month | Buyer_Username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 6 | June | A001 |
| 2022 | 6 | June | B002 |
| 2022 | 7 | July | C003 |
| 2022 | 7 | July | A001 |
| 2022 | 7 | July | D004 |
| 2022 | 8 | August | C003 |
| 2022 | 8 | August | E005 |
| 2022 | 9 | September | F006 |
| 2022 | 9 | September | G007 |
| 2022 | 9 | September | A001 |
| 2022 | 9 | September | B002 |
| 2022 | 9 | September | C003 |
| 2022 | 10 | October | D004 |
| 2022 | 10 | October | G007 |
| 2022 | 11 | November | H008 |
| 2022 | 12 | December | I009 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | H008 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | J010 |

The result I expected will be:

| Year | Month_Number | Month | New_Customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 6 | June | 2 |
| 2022 | 7 | July | 2 |
| 2022 | 8 | August | 1 |
| 2022 | 9 | September | 2 |
| 2022 | 10 | October | 0 |
| 2022 | 11 | November | 1 |
| 2022 | 12 | December | 1 |
| 2023 | 1 | January | 1 |

```
On June 2022,
count disinct First to June 2022 is (2) - nothing previous (0),
2 - 0 = 2

On July 2022,
count distinct First to July 2022 is (4) - count distinct First to June 2022 is (2),
4 - 2 = 2

On August 2022,
count distinct First to August 2022 is (5) - count distinct First to July 2022 is (4),
5 - 4 = 1

On September 2022,
count distinct First to September 2022 (7) - count distinct First to August 2022 is (5),
7 - 5 = 2

On October 2022, 
count distinct First to October 2022 (7) - count distinct First to September 2022 is (7),
7 - 7 = 0

On November 2022,
count distinct First to November (8) - count distinct First to October is (7),
8 - 7 = 1

On December 2022,
count distinct First to December (9) - count distinct First to November is (8),
9 - 8 = 1

On January 2023,
count distinct First to January 2023 (10) - count distinct First to November 2022 is (9),
10 - 9 = 1
```

How to do this with SQL to get this result (I'm working on Bigquery)
Thanks a lot (My english is not strong, Apologize)

I try:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT Buyer_Username) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY Year, Month
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       )
-
LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT Buyer_Username))
  OVER (PARTITION BY Year, Month 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS Something
```

It doesn't work just from syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to omit months that have no new buyers, this is rather simple: Per buyer get the first month, so you see in which month they were a new buyer. Then count new buyers per month.

```
select
  extract(year from first_datetime) as year,
  extract(month from first_datetime) as month_number,
  format_datetime('%B', first_datetime) as month,
  count(*) as new_customers
from
(
  select min(created_time) as first_datetime
  from main_table
  group by buyer_username
) firsttime_buyers
group by
  extract(year from first_datetime),
  extract(month from first_datetime),
  format_datetime('%B', first_datetime)
order by year, month_number;
```

If you need the zero-count months, then you must select all months first and then get the firsttime_buyers' counts:

```
with months as
(
  select distinct 
    extract(year from first_datetime) as year,
    extract(month from first_datetime) as month_number,
    format_datetime('%B', first_datetime) as month
  from main_table
)
, firsttime_buyers as
(
  select min(created_time) as first_datetime
  from main_table
  group by buyer_username
)
select 
  m.year, m.month_number, m.month,
  (
    select count(*)
    from firsttime_buyers ftb
    where extract(ftb.year from first_datetime) = m.year
    and extract(ftb.month from first_datetime) = m.month_number
  ) as new_customers
from months m
order by m.year, m.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MonthlyDistinctBuyers AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Created_Time) AS Year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Created_Time) AS Month_Number,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Buyer_Username) AS Distinct_Buyers
  FROM Main_table
  GROUP BY Year, Month_Number
),
PreviousMonthDistinctBuyers AS (
  SELECT
    Year,
    Month_Number,
    LAG(Distinct_Buyers) OVER (ORDER BY Year, Month_Number) AS Previous_Month_Distinct_Buyers
  FROM MonthlyDistinctBuyers
)
SELECT
  Year,
  Month_Number,
  FORMAT_DATE('%B', DATE(TIMESTAMP(Year, Month_Number, 1))) AS Month,
  Distinct_Buyers - IFNULL(Previous_Month_Distinct_Buyers, 0) AS New_Customers
FROM MonthlyDistinctBuyers
LEFT JOIN PreviousMonthDistinctBuyers
USING (Year, Month_Number)
ORDER BY Year, Month_Number;
```

Comment: From main table there is only column name 'Created_Time' Which is Datetime format so on  SELECT DISTINCT
    Year,
    Month_Number,
    Month
  FROM Main_table
Is not work

Comment: You didn't provide your table structure. I updated the query